# ALTER COLUMN WITHOUT DROP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to alter column within the table to be NULL from NOT NULL.
The problem is that table has one constraint, one trigger and 4 indexes.

Can I somehow alter that column without dropping and recreating everything?

Comment: Changing the `NULL`ability of a column does not require `DROP`ing it, or any `CONSTRAINT`s/`INDEX`es that reference it. What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: Yes, just alter the column using the normal syntax... https://dbfiddle.uk/lNfeflSy

Comment: Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object '****' is dependent on column '*****'.
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object '****' is dependent on column '***'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ****failed because one or more objects access this column. ..................

Comment: It cannot be changed using normal syntax...

Comment: If the column is part of a filtered index , in the WHERE clause, then it is not possible to ALTER it

Comment: Is it part of a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint? By definition all columns participating in a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint must be `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec sys.sp_depends 'object_name'

List all dependencies and then drop them an recreate everything.

SQL Managements studio offer option with SCRIPT AS CREATE and you can save all views, triggers, tables as backup...